# Is writing G-d's name in a regular word shaimos?

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names

In many words in the Hebrew language you have G-d's name in them. For example, in the word "chaim" in Hebrew there's a yud next to yud and in the world "el" it's an alef next to a lamod. If one writes these words on a paper would it have to go to shaimos? Also, what about in Hebrew names like "chizkihayu" or "yehoshua"?

Comment: Since two *yud*s together is not really a divine name, just a reference to a divine name, [it does not have the same holiness](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/32156). Certainly inside a name, where those letters are not being used to refer to a divine name at all, there should be no issue whatsoever with two *yud*s together.